# How to make an api completely independent from the main Django Project?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django project that is hosted internally, and this project feeds the database. I need an API that serves the data of that database to a public domain (that api does not do any DML only selects), but this API needs be hosted in a diferent machine and even if the project that is hosted internally explodes that api needs to keep working.

I am using DRF for the api
I did an api project that has its own apps, views, serializers  and models(those models connect to the db existing table like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/)) and only have the fields that I need represented. Is this the right way to do this or am I missing something? The thing that I am worried is if one of the columns of a model changes name i will have to change the model in the api, but that is a very rare modification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly but it seems from your question that you have a DJANGO project along with the DATABASE hosted on a particular machine. If that is the case then if your server goes down external API's will not be able to fetch your data.
If on the other hand you have a dedicated server or RDBMS for only your database then you will be able to fetch the data using any API connecting to that database server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).